# C# Excel Interop: Set multiple cell COMMENTS at once

Tags: c#, excel

I recently figured out how to write cell values in a range:

```
Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1], xlWorkSheet.Cells[10, 10]];
rng.Value = new string[,] { ... };
```

which speeds up my app enourmous, but I would also like to be able to set a whole range of cell comments! I only found the possibility to make a comment on a range of cells. A single comment. But it does not seem that something for it exists in the api.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set more than one cell comment at once, but you can copy comment from one cell and paste it to multiple cells:

```
var a1 = xlWorkSheet.Range("A1")
a1.ClearComments(); // just in case 
a1.AddComment("some comment");
a1.Copy();
a1.Resize(10, 10).PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteComments);
```